Как найти связанные элементы массива в JS?
У меня есть массив объектов.


let arr = [{name: "a", bind: "b"}, {name: "b", bind: "a"}, {name: "c"}]



Мне нужно из данного массива объектов найти связанные элементы через bind.

Например в верхнем коде связаны два объекта с именем a и b (bind: "b", bind: "a").  Функция должна в данном примере вернуть [{name: "a", bind: "b"}, {name: "b", bind: "a"}].



let arr = [{name: "a", bind: "b"}, {name: "b", bind: "a"}, {name: "c", bind: "b"}]




Второй пример в коде выше. Функция должна вернуть [{name: "a", bind: "b"}, {name: "b", bind: "a"}, {name: "c", bind: "b"}].

В одной группе связанных элементов может быть сколько угодно объектов.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Твой пример слишком минимальный... Что делать если совпадений больше? Что делать если есть другие группы для совпадений?


Мне нужно из данного массива объектов найти связанные элементы

Предложу такой вариант...


const test = arr => arr.reduce((obj, o, i) => {
    if (!obj.i.includes(i)) {
        const j = arr.findIndex(({name, bind}) => o.bind === name && o.name === bind)
        if (~j) {
            obj.i.push(j)
            obj.res.push([o, arr[j]])
        }
    }
    return obj
}, {i: [], res: []}).res

let arr = [
    {name: "a", bind: "b"}, {name: "b", bind: "a"}, 
    {name: "c"},
]

console.log('Данные ТСа', test(arr))

arr = [
    {name: "a", bind: "b"}, {name: "b", bind: "a"}, 
    {name: "c"},
    {name: "d", bind: "f"}, {name: "f", bind: "d"}, 
]

console.log('Добавлена еще группа совпадений', test(arr))



